# A simple question about 1-norm

Tags: algebraic-topology, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group, if $\mu \in l^{1}(\Gamma)$, then what is the 1-norm of $\mu$, I mean $||\mu||_{1}=?$. As we know, $l^{1}(\Gamma)=\{(\alpha_{x})_{x\in\Gamma}: \sum\limits_{x}|\alpha_{x}|<\infty\}$, then $||\mu||_{1}=\sum\limits_{x}|\alpha_{x}|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a standard notation.

Comment: And if we regard $f\in l^{1}(\Gamma)$ as a function $\Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, what is the 1-norm of $f$ now? Is it $||f||_{1}=\sum\limits_{t\in \Gamma}|f(t)|$?

Comment: Yes, of course, this is the standard $l^1$-norm.